# Unusual lasting consumption of hard disk space with update of (kernel) two days ago - why?

Tags: apt, kernel, updates

Normally I wouldn't notice, but here I have a server ubuntu 22.04 with tight space of 8 GB (originally thin client).
Usually at updates, kernel updates, the remaining space stays about the same. Two days ago at apt upgrade it had already announced to take some 600 MB additional space, something unusual. I did agree, though, and the remaining space shrunk likewise. Strange also that at the end, an ncurses screen showed, stating something like the kernel was not the expected one, and I had to reboot through this interface. This usually never happens. There is no X on the system.
It still runs pretty okay, but still takes significantly more space than before (around 0,5 GB). apt autoremove and purge-old-kernels didn't offer any relief.
Like this, I do run out of space in short notice. 
 Can anyone help out and explain what happened, please?

(The hard drive is a non-standard flash drive, so upgrading won't be that simple.)

[Added 5 days later:]
After the next update, this same text popped up again:
"Newer kernel available     The currently running kernel version is 5.15.0-82-generic which is not the expected kernel version 5.15.0-83-generic. Restarting the system to load the new kernel will not be handled automatically, so you should consider rebooting."
There is nothing fantastic that I had fiddled with. All most normal. Why does it always find a kernel different from the one expected?

Edited as by request:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 7.46 GiB, 8012390400 bytes, 15649200 sectors
Disk model: 8GB SATA Flash D
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 86C1689B-2846-433D-9E46-B53705D7FB84

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048  1103871  1101824  538M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1103872 15646719 14542848  6.9G Linux filesystem

Archived and active journals take up 56.0M in the file system.

-16 142f96db4a8c4643a2569269593ea032 Wed 2023-08-16 13:45:28 CEST—Wed 2023-08-16 15:51:46 CEST
-15 599afea047be4d37b76a392fda09dd64 Wed 2023-08-16 15:57:56 CEST—Wed 2023-08-16 22:15:34 CEST
-14 5c7db573e8524663bbc11ab823a07bc2 Thu 2023-08-17 17:26:23 CEST—Thu 2023-08-17 17:32:36 CEST
-13 26865784b7f2454c8a09cfe23947b0ea Thu 2023-08-17 17:33:10 CEST—Thu 2023-08-17 17:37:44 CEST
-12 059439fb89ce44198870ffcb6ce3268a Thu 2023-08-17 17:38:47 CEST—Thu 2023-08-17 17:40:05 CEST
-11 eeebce9a1c9745849141f690e861e25f Thu 2023-08-17 17:41:10 CEST—Fri 2023-08-18 20:32:52 CEST
-10 6ba1c5efe28c4c5991452877b4b0ca8e Fri 2023-08-18 20:33:29 CEST—Sat 2023-08-19 21:09:56 CEST
 -9 735efb752bdb4389acc877fa61a03b60 Sat 2023-08-19 22:12:47 CEST—Sun 2023-08-20 12:09:16 CEST
 -8 d89b803f33464f2fac5d9090d9734787 Sun 2023-08-20 13:08:32 CEST—Sun 2023-08-20 14:01:06 CEST
 -7 66915d29b549463aa164a258d5946155 Sun 2023-08-20 14:01:42 CEST—Sun 2023-08-20 14:08:11 CEST
 -6 8abe630392d7452ea1c77c8c0ed47424 Sun 2023-08-20 14:16:52 CEST—Sun 2023-08-20 14:24:59 CEST
 -5 931d0c61491d484d87fc95a59e4cb677 Sun 2023-08-20 14:25:34 CEST—Sun 2023-08-20 15:24:54 CEST
 -4 ddc5c347da584047a7c6513e851407fd Sun 2023-08-20 15:33:18 CEST—Mon 2023-08-21 16:54:36 CEST
 -3 e1c7d2c07d824c61a3b6c2c79fec02c5 Mon 2023-08-21 17:16:28 CEST—Thu 2023-08-24 13:19:58 CEST
 -2 7d2feefdb5b54c7bb56034523e3cb16b Thu 2023-08-24 13:52:25 CEST—Fri 2023-08-25 06:10:35 CEST
 -1 2a9a935d50b9461599cfa512f899fb3a Fri 2023-08-25 06:11:11 CEST—Mon 2023-08-28 18:00:06 CEST
  0 cf26bf6149704abd9311878b012a7930 Mon 2023-08-28 18:07:26 CEST—Wed 2023-08-30 20:17:15 CEST
```

Comment: Output of `ls -al /boot` command may help us. Or, otherwise have you been able to find where this space is gone? For example, did you check for unusual large files in `/var/log`?

Comment: It happened exactly at that kernel update of a few days ago. `64M     /var/log/` 
In /boot there are two kernels, of around 110 MB each. 
Though the idea is great, and I actually find 1.1 GB in /snap.And I haven't installed anything over there AFAIK.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show us `sudo fdisk -l;df -m;sudo journalctl --disk-usage;sudo journalctl  --list-boots`. Read `man journalctl` about the `--vacuum-*` commands to reduce the amount of disk the logs take, by discarding older data.